# Sending sms via Twilio with link

Tags: java, sms, twilio

I'm trying to send sms using the [twilio-java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install/) helper library on a Java application.
I would like to include a link in my sms and alt its text.
How is that possible?
Here's my code:

```
        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

        Account account = client.getAccount();

        SmsFactory smsFactory = account.getSmsFactory();
        Map<String, String> smsParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        smsParams.put("To", to);
        smsParams.put("From", PHONE_NUMBER); 
        smsParams.put("Body", text);
        Sms sms = smsFactory.create(smsParams);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SMS doesn't really do this - you can put the URL in the message like so:

```
http://www.twilio.com
```

But you *cannot* do this in HTML style like so:

[Twilio](http://www.twilio.com)

SMS is just raw text, then your device finds the URLs and makes them into links. The Twilio 'Url' parameter is for making calls, rather than for SMS.